# How to play video while it is downloading using AVPro video in unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, download, video-streaming

I want to play the video simultaneously while it is downloading via unitywebrequest. Will AVPro video support this? If so please provide me some guidance, as i am new to unity and avpro video. I can able to play the video which is downloaded fully through FullscreenVideo.prefab in AVPro demo. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main options you could use for displaying the video while it is still downloading.

**Through livestream**

You can stream a video to AVPro video using the "absolute path or URL" option on the media player component, then linking this to a stream in rtsp, MPEG-DASH, HLS, or HTTP progressive streaming format. Depending on what platforms you will be targeting some of these options will work better than others

A table of which file format supports what platform can be found in the AVProVideo Usermanual that is included with AVProVideo from page 12 and onwards.

If you want to use streaming you also need to set the "internet access" option to "required" in the player settings, as a video cannot stream without internet access. 
A video that is being streamed will automatically start/resume playing when enough video is buffered.

This does however require a constant internet connection which may not be ideal if you're targeting mobile devices, or unnecessary if you're planning to play videos in a loop.

**HLS m3u8**

HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) works by cutting the overall stream into shorter, manageable hunks of data. These chunks will then get downloaded in sequence regardless of how long the stream is. m3u8 is a file format that works with playlists that keeps information on the location of multiple media files instead of an entire video, this can then be fed into a HLS player that will play the small media files in sequence as dictated in the m3u8 file.

using this method is usefull if you're planning to play smaller videos on repeat as the user will only have to download each chunk of the video once, which you can then store for later use.

You can also make these chunks of video as long or short as you want, and set a buffer of how many chunks you want to have pre-loaded. if for example you set the chunk size to 5 seconds, with a buffer of 5 videos the only loading time you'll have is when loading the first 25 seconds of the video. once these first 5 chunks are loaded it will start playing the video and load the rest of the chunks in the background, without interrupting the video (given your internet speed can handle it)

a con to this would be that you have to convert all your videos to m3u8 yourself. a tool such as [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) can help with this though.

**references**

- [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming)
- [m3u8](https://www.lifewire.com/m3u8-file-2621956)
- [AVPro documentation](http://www.renderheads.com/content/docs/AVProVideoClassReference/class_render_heads_1_1_media_1_1_a_v_pro_video_1_1_media_player.html#af9a949b895cc7872b6a99ae7510c8c1a)

Comment: Thank you @remy_rm for your answer. But, Is there any way to stream video from the downloaded data. So it will reduce internet usage of the user.

Comment: Yes there is. If you use the HLS/m3u8 method you can save the downloaded files like you would with any other file, and the open that file later instead of streaming it. you can use WWW (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) to download it like so `WWW www = new WWW("http://yourSite.com/Videos/SomeVideo.m3u8");` then save the video using `File.WriteAllBytes(<Path where you want to save>, www.bytes);` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.WriteAllBytes.html. 

You can then perform a check to see if file exists, if not download it, if there is play from saved file

Comment: This will download only the text file of different stream options available, not the video.